# BeanPropertyRowMapper alternative for JPA entities

Tags: java, spring

Spring has an excellent [org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.java) that helps in queries using jdbctemplate. This class maps database columns to bean fields and is very effective.

I have jpa entities in my project that column annotation of the field differs, like:

```
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = true, length = 255)
private String desc;
```

When using BeanPropertyRowMapper, it will look for a column field "desc" to match.
How can I achieve that if an annotation exists for this field, use the column name given ("description" in this case) and fallback to field name if it does not exist?

Any clue on this subject?

Comment: Why do you select JPA entities with Spring JDBC? Why don't you use JPA queries?

Comment: I use them with JPA queries in another project. In this project we want to reuse JPA entities from the former project, and JPA will be overkill since this project will be for reporting (just selects)

Comment: Have the same question currently. In my case (using hibernate) i need to make a select using Spring's JDBC Template, because the hibernateDAO.findByQuery(hqlQuery) does some expensive flushing and dirty-checking which I don't need. Doing this query with jdbcTemplate avoids all the hibernate overhead. But I just would like to have the mapping from row to object which respects the field annotations.